# Number Theory Prove a complete square 1,11,111

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, repunit-numbers

I have to prove that every number in the series 
11,111,1111 ...
Is not a complete square,
Can you give me a clue how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you mean that no number in that series (besides $1$) *is* a perfect square?

Comment: Hi Tanner,exactly

Comment: In English, the double negative “*no* number ... is *not*” would mean “*every* number is”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I think $1$ can be discarded, because actually $1=1^2$...)

Hint: Consider the numbers in modulo 4. Then compare with $x^2 \mod 4$.

Comment: Thank you Matti!